# linux binary independent of shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, binary, portability, ldd

I have a C++ program that depends on quite a few libraries (some common system libraries like libjpeg some personal libraries that are not installed system wide). The Program compiles well on machine A (Debian Squeeze). I would like to run the program on machine B (Ubuntu maveric) and machine C (Arch). Assume that both machines B+C are extremly mininmal installations. Don't expect to find ANY libraries that my program uses on there and if there are any they are not the same version.

Is there any program that can scan my program for ALL dependencies (using ldd or something) gather all those dependencies, and generate a script that will tell the binary to use these and only these libs it comes with on any other system ?

Thank you !

Comment: good luck with this; alternatively you could just deliver source as is the convention

Comment: I'm not planning to "deliver". I want this for my own use. I have the source code but recompiling can be a real pain. For an example compilers usually assume that it is safe to use a different version of a lib. However that is not always the case - i want to be 100% sure that the program uses the EXACT same libs on every machine.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are doing it right. It should be easy to build from source. I'd concentrate on sorting out that problem if I were you.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sounds like you are using a much more intelligent build system than i do. Care to share ? (Keep in mind i don't want to write specific Makefiles, Cmake findscripts or whatever for each system)

Comment: [klik](http://code.google.com/p/klikclient/) used to be able to automatically create recipes from Debian packages and dependencies, but it's not been updated in a while and the .deb format has been updated a bit in that time so I'm not sure if it still works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but it seems like you want to ship the libraries with your package, and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to force the linker to look in your shipped library directory before anything else.

If there's more to it, I can revise my answer as I have some experience with this. Just want to make sure I know what you're asking for.

Comment: That sounds right. So would that work ? Does the compiler (gcc in my case) use libs in LD_LIBRARY_PATH always before, say libs in /usr/lib ? Also if that is the case: Is there any program that atomatically parses the output from ldd -v (that should gove me all dependencies right?) and copies all libs into a directory ?

Comment: +1 to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH solution.  The other option would be to make static builds of all dependent libraries and link them all together into one monolithic binary.

Comment: Joekk, that's right. The order is rpaths (lib directories baked in to the executable asking for it), LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then the default paths in /etc/ld.so.conf. Look at http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the answer to your question is to link statically, say with g++ -static.

Comment: +1, provided you isolate the static build to release mode and not present on debug/develop mode.

Comment: My only difference between debug and release is -strip.

Comment: Then I would say that if you're including anything other than standard libs that this is silly for the mere fact that build times take longer.

Comment: I've got enough disk cache and cpu power that I don't have to care.

Comment: I think I'm a little too used to needing to build and transfer the binary onto an embeddedarm board.